# Why is chrome looking for '/assets/otis_redding.png'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, modernizr

I've got a Rails app I'm working on.  Totally unclear, but using Chrome in not-hidden mode, keeps producing a request to my local server that is looking for `/assets/otis_redding.png`.  This does not happen in chrome hidden mode or with firefox or safari.  I'm usually good at debugging rails business but this is weird.

Any thoughts on what is happening?

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-20 09:11:25 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 26ms (Views: 24.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/otis_redding.png"):
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.3) lib/quiet_assets.rb:23:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/jd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/jd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/jd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

It would appear that this problem is related to modernizr?

[image: https://cl.ly/image/0Z1E1p1n000Q/Image%202014-11-20%20at%209.25.47%20AM.png]

But the modernizr code in question doesn't seem to be calling this.  I'm way confused.

[image: https://cl.ly/image/2X393S432w21/Image%202014-11-20%20at%209.27.28%20AM.png]

Comment: Does your application make use of the Mimo Studio theme called "Grider" at all? I notice that `otis_redding.png` is one of the background images included with that theme. See http://mimothemes.com/demos/grider/wp-content/themes/mimo_grider/images/backgrounds/otis_redding/

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.